# Interview module

Tags: forms

Drupal 7: 
In my new website there i want to add an interview section.
I will explain it.
I need a section to add client interview details.
In this section there may be some questions and its answers.
How can we add questions and its answers?I will create a content type for this.

But i want to know how can we setup fields for an input form for this?

I'm sorry ,if it is a foolish question.

[image]

Comment: You can add the fields from `admin/structure/types/manage/{your_content_type}/fields`.

Comment: thanks develkar...
I know how to add fields and manage fields.
I need to know how can we organize the input form.
Suppose  i have a content type "interviews"
In this content type i want the fields Questions , answers.
If we have 5 questions like q1,q2,q3,q4 and q5 ,when we add q1 the next step would be the option to add its answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module,

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be viewed and edited separately too

Then add field collection field with fields question and answer. Give Number of values as unlimited .

Comment: field Collection is very useful.Please watch : http://youtu.be/1V1ofpgUw-Y

Answer (score 1):

You can use webform for this. By using webform you can create a set of questions and then that form can be given to all attendees, who will be giving answers. So you can have whole set of data from different users who have given answers to your questions.

[drupal.org/project/webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)

Comment: but we cannot give a specific set of questions.its something like interviewing an actor or a business man.no predefined question.User needs to enter the interview details which is already done.